# An unlimited slideshow creating new slides on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, masterslider

I'd like to make a sort of unlimited slider with previous and next buttons, showing one slide in the browser at a time, (without loading too many slides in the DOM at once, maybe 3 slides loaded in the DOM altogether)

Once the second slide shows, you click next to show the third slide, and then I'd like to dynamically create 3 new slides on the fly so that there's more slides available in the slideshow. Then do this continuously.

Comment: Great...what is the specific code problem or question?

Comment: You want max 3 or to keep adding indefinitely?   If you're changing the content, you don't need to add any.  Otherwise, search for infinite scroll.

Comment: I'll have to throw up a codepen to demonstrate how far I got. Im wondering what's the strategy for this. I'm not sure I'm doing it the way it should be done. Infinite scroll is a bit different. I want to do an unlimited slideshow left to right, without loading all the photos in the DOM. Want to show one at a time and load as user clicks next.